# Highcharts Dynamic candlestick

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would like to make a dynamic chart with `candlestick` type , I tried to edit the dynamic example by add `type: 'candlestick'` to series but it doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/hppyr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are passing line data to a candlestick
OHLC needs its data as an array of array, with the each element on inner array having 5 values as 
`[x,o,h,l,c]`

```
series.addPoint([
    x,
    Math.random()*100,
    Math.random()*100,
    Math.random()*100,
    Math.random()*100
    ], true, true);


data.push([
    time + i * 1000,
    Math.random()*100,
    Math.random()*100,
    Math.random()*100,
    Math.random()*100
    ]);
```

API Reference @ http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.data
jsFiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/SykAf/